# pop up until jquery finishes processing

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jquery and I need to figure out how to do the following:

I have a submit button on my page and when clicked a jquery function is executed. The function will load some information from mysql and echo a table with that information.

My problem is that this takes time and meanwhile the user is waiting or even resubmitting.

What I would like is to have a popup screen that will be displayed before I start fetching the data from mysql and removed after the data is echoed onto the page.

What would I be looking for? what is this called? how can I implement such a think.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form-lecturer-login').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//I need: Display a pop up

//This is working : Code to fetch mysql data and echo a table

//I need: Remove popup
}
```

Here's my full code:
pastebin.com/JVCfWbLD

Comment: after submit the form will reload

Comment: u can use "messi model" http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/    by mess fan

Comment: @PSR no, please check my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 .blockUI() in jQuery .
```

I think this will solve your problem.

[block ui](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

It blocks the screen until you unblock it.It is very good plug in.

Comment: sure :) but I am trying to figure out how to make it work, blocking is working but calling '$.unblockUI;' doesn't

Comment: ok so its not working because inside the submit handler I make many post requests to php scripts that are async. so as soon as popup appears it disapears. Any work arround?

Comment: no the popup appears then disapears directly because the POST calls actually returned. Since I guess post returns before the success funtion is executed

Answer (score 1):

Since you are actually using jQuery `submit` and not AJAX, the page is waiting for your server-side handler to process the data. Try this:

Put these two lines in the `<header>` of your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Then modify your code like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

           $(function() {
                $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false
           });

           $('#form-lecturer-login').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );

                    //Your working processing code here.

                $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "close" );
           }

       });
```

Then in the body of your HTML:

```
<div id="#dialog-modal" title="Stand by...">
  <p>Your data is loading, please stand by...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work :$ nothign happened, no popup was displayed. are you sure the includs are OK?

Comment: and Your data is loading, please stand by.. was displayed in the body

Comment: @Kam I changed the style to a function call... check above ... I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a loading bar when the user submits.
Here is a demo

http://bokehman.com/loading